# Linking the Table of Contents in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I am trying to link my table of contents to the respective chapters etc. of  my.tex file when exported as a .pdf. However, I have a problem with the link to my bibliography. The bibliography link in my table of contents becomes linked, however it gets linked to the section before it. My code is below. Any thoughts?

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{STAT3585,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{pstcol}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[colorlinks = true,
               linkcolor = black,
               urlcolor  = black,
               citecolor = blue,
               anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cancel}
    \usepackage{polynom}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{comment}
    
    
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{exa}{Example}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{note}{Note}[chapter]
    
    
    \begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Basics}
    
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
    
    \bibitem{} ....
    
    \end{thebibliography}
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `\phantomsection` to provide a target for the link to the bibliography. Make sure to use it (and your `\addcontentsline`) on the same page as the bibliography and not the previous page like in your example. You can ensure this by adding `\clearpage` before them.

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
%    \usepackage{pstcol}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[colorlinks = true,
               linkcolor = black,
               urlcolor  = black,
               citecolor = blue,
               anchorcolor = blue]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{cancel}
    \usepackage{polynom}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{comment}
    
    
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{exa}{Example}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[chapter]
    \newtheorem{note}{Note}[chapter]
    
    
    \begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Basics}
    
    
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
    
    \bibitem{} ....
    
    \end{thebibliography}
    
    \end{document}
```